# Display of image on image Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to make an on hover display of my site products.
My initial though was to use the show/hide jQuery function after that I though using arrays was my best bet but I have 0 knowledge off

[This is exactly what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBNzZ.jpg)

When you hover any product it's array value is displayed below in a container with it's various info

This is the code I have for now:

```
<script>
 function display() {
  var imgArray = ["E11.png", "E11BIO.png", "E22-clear-2018.png", "E22BIO.png"];
 }
</script>

    <img src="E11.png" onHover="display();">
    <img src="E11BIO.png" onHover="display();">
    <img src="E22-clear-2018.png" onHover="display();">
    <img src="E22BIO.png" onHover="display();">

    <div class="display">
        <img src="imgArray[i]" style="width:50px;">
    </div>
```

I know my code is trash but it is only to illustrate my approach, I am working on making it more humanlike but my inexperience is stopping me for completing my task. 
Any related material code even tutorial on how to use arrays with html is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate question check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769016/display-image-on-text-link-hover-css-only

Comment: @RaghavRaman  Every image1 is bound to another image2 and everytime user hovers any image1 image2 is displayed and that should have for image3 to image4 and so on. I don't think this is possible through pure html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your array of bottles looks something like in my fiddle below. I would then first start by adding your bottles programmatically to your page. That will save you alot of work in the long term when bottles/ images or data from your backend change.

Therefore you would need some `addBottle` function to display the bottle on your "shelf". In that function you attach the eventhandlers for the bottles for `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`.

```js
let bottles = [
 {img: 'someImageReference 1', title: 'some Title 1', year: '1900'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 2', title: 'some Title 2', year: '1901'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 3', title: 'some Title 3', year: '1902'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 4', title: 'some Title 4', year: '1903'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 5', title: 'some Title 5', year: '1904'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 6', title: 'some Title 6', year: '1905'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 7', title: 'some Title 7', year: '1906'},
  {img: 'someImageReference 8', title: 'some Title 8', year: '1907'},
];

for(var i = 0; i < bottles.length; i++) {
 addBottle(bottles[i]);
}

function addBottle( bottleData ) {
 let $bottle = $('<span></span>').addClass('bottle');
  let $shelf = $('.shelf');
  $shelf.append($bottle);
  $bottle.on('mouseenter', function() {
   displayBottleData( bottleData );
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
   hideBottleDetails();
  });
}

function hideBottleDetails() {
 let $bartender = $('#bartender');
  $bartender.empty();
}

function displayBottleData( data ) {
 let $bartender = $('#bartender');
 hideBottleDetails();
  $bartender.text('This bottle is from ' + data.year);
}
```

```css
#bartender {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 2em;
  color: white;
}

.shelf {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottle{
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;  
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shelf"></div>

<div id="bartender">
  
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "adding your bottles programmatically to your page"  even though your answer is exactly what I am looking for, I am struggling with implementing it on my end due to my inexperience I am getting 0 output so far even though I copied 100%