# How to ignore display Image On Text Link Hover CSS Only when below a certain screen size

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover

I used this article to add a display image on text link hover (see link and css used below) and it works great, however I want to ignore this css when viewing on mobile. It is important to note that this should be all css. Any ideas?

```css
.hover_img a {
  position: relative;
}

.hover_img a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}

.hover_img a:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover_img">
  <a href="#">Show Image<span><img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="image" height="100" /></span></a>
</div>
```

[Display Image On Text Link Hover CSS Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769016/display-image-on-text-link-hover-css-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hover media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover).

> The "hover" CSS media feature can bu used to test whether the user's
>   primary input mechanism can hover over elements.

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
  .hover_img a span {
    display: none;
  }
  .hover_img a:hover span {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (hover: none) {
  .hover_img a span {
    display: block; /* always show on e.g. a touch device */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hover_img">
  <a href="#">Show Image<span><img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="image" height="100" /></span></a>
</div>
```

Or you can use normal media query as you want. Like this:

(view on full page view)

```css
.hover_img a span {
  display: none;
}

.hover_img a:hover span {
  display: block;
}


/* don't use hover for devices smaller than 720px */

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .hover_img a span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hover_img">
  <a href="#">Show Image<span><img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="image" height="100" /></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was writing the same answers, you where a little faster. :P Good solutions indeed, but for the hover media query I would be a little more cautious, since there are a lot of 'hybrid' devices with touch AND pointer devices. You could get some unexpected behaviours.

Comment: @dgnca thanks for the quick responses, when I try adding these it actually starts displaying the "hover_img" on mobile. Maybe im not integrating properly?

Comment: @dgknca The site is https://www.thomasjgardner.com if you want to see what’s going on.

Comment: @thomas isn't gives desired result?

Comment: @dgknca no I’d like mobile site not to display the hover_img, apologies if I didn’t explain properly.