# Customize preview image for github pages

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-pages, social-media

is it possible to customize the image that you see as a preview when posting the link to your github pages?

I feel like they specifically address the issue for github repositories [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/customizing-your-repositorys-social-media-preview), but I dont know how to do this for github pages. Specifically, I want my github page to not just display just a grey image of nothing, when it is showing up on my Featured section on LinkedIn:

[image]

Comment: There's a whole slew of things, and different sites require different tags. Take a look at https://metatags.io/

Comment: I think this link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769016/display-image-on-text-link-hover-css-only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This preview image taking from website [meta tags](https://metatags.io/). Specifically for LinkedIn enough to use:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="preview_image.jpg" />
```

Example from [my LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandrtovmach/):
[image]

The first two featured items are my [personal website](https://alexandrtovmach.com) pages, and each of them has separate meta tags. It hosted on GitHub Pages, but it doesn't matter where to host. Here is how it's can be done:

```
<head>
      {/* all socials */}
      <meta property="og:image" content={previewImageSrc} />
      {/* twitter */}
      <meta name="twitter:image" content={previewImageSrc} />
</head>
```

[full example (gatsby + react-helmet)](https://github.com/alexandrtovmach/alexandrtovmach.com/blob/master/src/containers/SEO/index.tsx)

Comment: Sorry, this is probably way too late but I'm trying to get this solution to work for my jekyll site. 

Where exactly do I put the stuff from the `head` tag section in my site repository? In the index.html file?

Here's the code base for reference: https://github.com/sharmaabhishekk/sharmaabhishekk.github.io

Comment: meta tags should be placed into `<head>`, which in your case contains here https://github.com/sharmaabhishekk/sharmaabhishekk.github.io/blob/master/_includes/head.html

Comment: I tried adding the two meta tags in the head section in my `head.html` but it still doesn't work on twitter card validator for some reason.
The code is still on the same link as above. I tried using full image url, relative paths to images as well as variables but it still doesn't change anything

Comment: it works, just checked with https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator. it can be cache issue, so you need to wait for a while after making changes

Comment: yes, since posting the comment, I'd stumbled upon the way to fix it and I had pushed the changes to main. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried the answer above but my og:image still doesn't reflect on my linkedIn profile. After further inspection , I found out that LinkedIn caches link preview content for 7 days. Changes you made will not reflect immediately unless you inspect your site using the [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_pulse_read%3BFZdZNYJ%2BRFKzlwHydr%2Fmmg%3D%3D).

Credits to this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-clear-linkedin-link-preview-cache-ananda-kannan-p