# github.io website icon/favicon not rendering

Tags: html, github-pages, favicon

I have been trying to get website icon/favicon to work on my new GitHub.io site for a while and have not had any luck. I have been working in my home directory where my index.html file is located.

location of my favicon:
[image: location of my favicon]

In index.html's  section, I have tried all the below at different times and even did hard refresh:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-png" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="icon" href="http://mindyng.github.io/mindy.ico?v=2" />
```

None of the above have worked.

What I expect:
same favicon from my previous website:
[image: same favicon from my previous website]

What I got:
currently what is showing up:
[image: currently what is showing up]

favicon not rendering on my LinkedIn page:
[image: favicon not rendering on my LinkedIn page]

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `default` layout as shown [here.](https://github.com/mindyng/mindyng.github.io/blob/master/index.html#L2) which gives you the code
**Header**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
     </head>
    <body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cv">CV</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
```

**And in between you have your own code in which you have used the `favicon`, and it is outside the first `head` tag, and inside the second, which is causing the problem.**
**Footer**:

```
</div>
<footer>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="mailto:mindyng8855@gmail.com">email</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://github.com/mindyng">github.com/mindyng</a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Put the favicon inside the head tag of [the layout](https://github.com/mindyng/mindyng.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) or do not close the `head` tag in the layout, instead close it in the `{{ content }}`.**

Comment: Thank you. So what I got from your suggestion is to copy what I had in my index.html header to my _layouts/default.html. I did that and my favicon has yet to show up in my LI profile. Please advise

Comment: favicon finally showed up for chrome (thank you!) though why doesnt it show up on LinkedIn page?

Comment: I do not think that favicon will be shown on LinkedIn, instead 'og:image' will be shown.

Comment: this helped a lot more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743304/customize-preview-image-for-github-pages

Answer (score 0):

looks like the issue was on LI side. their code update eventually got my github.io site icon to render about a year or more ago

[image: screeenshot from my LI page's Featured Carousel]